# Rails asset compilation timing out on Apple Silicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading from a 2015 to 2020 (M1) Macbook Pro, and just transferred a couple of Rails 5 projects over. Apart from the hardware the environments are essentially the same AFAICT (same project versions, same gems, same OS). One of the transferred projects loads fine, but on the other CSS compilation is super slow, taking over 30 seconds on each recompile, which causes the Foreman workers to timeout and the pages never load. Asset compilation for the same project takes 5 seconds on my old machine.

I tried changing `config.assets.debug` from **true** to **false** but it takes just as long. Wondering what could be causing this?

Comment: You are running a completely different CPU architecture though. Are you running this in Rosetta 2 in x86?

Comment: No I'm running Ruby 2.7.3 for ARM. I maybe naively thought I could just brew install my new environment like I normally do. Was feeling pretty good bc I hadn't run into any problems and everything's been super fast (including my other Rails app!). I haven't been able to find anything about Apple Silicon affecting Rails asset compilation or other fundamentals - on the contrary, it seems to work [quite well](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/tips-and-tricks-for-developing-rails-applications-on-apple-silicon/77089). And asset compilation wasn't affected on the other Rails app I ported.

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT!

The proximal cause was the autoprefixer-rails gem (which is a dependency of bootstrap gem), but when I dug deeper it turned out I was inadvertently running an older version of Node (v12.14.0). Installing latest Node version (v16.2.0) cleared up the issue entirely.